# I can see TouchPad option in my Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: touchpad, hp

I use the Hp-ProBook and I've installed ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. At first, everything is working fine but after some time 2 finger scroll automatically stop working and I've no idea why also when I try to find touchpad option in my setting I'm not able to find it

If anyone can help me with this please do.

[image]